# Html code not working in Safari, but working in all other browsers

Tags: html, safari

And I think it's not possible to submit the form in Safari browser

This is working fine in all browsers except safari

```
<form action="/commonDashboard" name="loginForm" method="post" autocomplete="off" id="loginForm">
    <div>
        <label>User Email ID</label>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Enter your Email Address" id="userEmail" name="userEmail" tabindex="1" />
    </div>
    <div>
        <label>Password</label>
        <input type="password" placeholder="Enter your password" id="userPassword" name="userPassword" tabindex="2" />
    </div>
    <div>
        <input type="button" value="Sign In" onclick="validatelogin();" tabindex="3" />
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: This is impossible to answer without MUCH more detail.

Comment: Can you post your validatelogin() function and also any other information?

Answer (score 0):

1. Change `type="button"` to `type="submit"`
2. Remove `onclick="validatelogin();"`
3. Assuming validatelogin is NOT performing any Ajax, change `<form action="/commonDashboard"` to 
   `<form action="/commonDashboard" onsubmit="return validatelogin()"` and have that function return true to allow submit or false to stop

or better add

```
window.onload=function() {
  document.getElementById("loginForm").onsubmit=validatelogin;
}
```

In any case, please post the function so we can see what it does

Comment: let me try this first.